# Razor ternary logic prints the entire string rather the model values?

Tags: c#, razor, logic, ternary

I have been working with an logic statement which keeps giving me error as there is a syntax error but canot find where this syntax error is located?

I basically want to change between two style sets given value of a boolean

```
        var imageStyles = Model.isSelected ? "background-position-x: Model.CropPositionX%; background-image: url(Model.ContentUrl);" : "background -position: Model.CropPosition%; background-image: url(Model.ContentUrl);";
```

but when i add it in my div tag Is the variable `imageStyles` rendered as a string, and the values of the model is not taken... What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the '@', so that the code is interpreted as C# and not as a raw String. Example of usage:

```
 var imageStyles = Model.isSelected ? "background-position-x: "+@Model.CropPositionX+"%; background-image: url("+@Model.ContentUrl+");" : "background -position:" + @Model.CropPosition+"%; background-image: url("+@Model.ContentUrl+");";
```

You could also use string interpolation, depending on the version of C# used by your razor view engine.

In that case, it would look like this (much cleaner, in my opinion):

```
 var imageStyles = Model.isSelected ? $"background-position-x: {Model.CropPositionX}%; background-image: url({Model.ContentUrl});" : "background -position: {Model.CropPosition}%; background-image: url({Model.ContentUrl});";
```